# MySQL container liveness and readiness probes work but cause a lot of error logs in Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

In my deployment I tried using

```
      readinessProbe:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 3306
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
        periodSeconds: 10
      livenessProbe:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 3306
```

and also

```
      readinessProbe:
        exec:
          command: ["mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
          ...
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command: ["mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
          ...
```

both work as the cluster recognizes the states correctly, but the logs are flooded with

- case 1: "Got an error reading communication packets"
- case 2: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

How can I out of the box, without an extra script, make a readiness probe without log errors. E.g. can I use the credentials as env variables somehow in the probes?

Comment: If you exec into the pod can you run your `mysqladmin` ping command without errors or prompts to authenticate? If not then you'll need to mount a mysql user credential into the pod that you can then refer to in the probes. Alternatively you can just use a tcp port check as a probe but that runs the risk of the port being open but the database being dead and kubernetes won't see that and will add the pod to the service.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: "Got an error reading communication packets"**

This error is due to the fact that you want to transfer a lot of data in one request, and thus a similar error may occur. To solve this problem, you need to increase the max_allowed_packet variable.

The  max_allowed_packet variable is responsible for the maximum data size you can transfer in one request.

The default value of the variable max_allowed_packet is 16 megabytes, so let's make sure of this, let's use queries:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Values are specified in bytes.

You can change the values of max_allowed_packet through the configuration file.

```
$. vim /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf
```

Restart the database.

```
$. service mysqld restart;
```

Above information is derived from this [link](https://it-inzhener.com/en/articles/detail/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets#:%7E:text=The%20error%20is%20called%20%22Got,to%20increase%20the%20max_allowed_packet%20variable) on Mysql error - Got an error reading communication packets.

**Case 2: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"**

The error log happens due to insufficient access and MySQL database privileges. As a result, the system releases a typical warning that confirms the MySQL error log and affects the root user, although some inputs, values, and elements are correct.

Hence try [resetting your root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html).